# Get data from excel worksheet and copy it into the active workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to using VBA and have found the code below. It works fine but I need all the rows in the source file. How can I change the code so I'm not limited to using the row numbers as the will be differten every time.

```
Private Sub Import1_Click()
' Get customer workbook...
Dim customerBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

' make weak assumption that active workbook is the target
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get the customer workbook
filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)

' assume range is A1 - G10 in sheet1
' copy data from customer to target workbook
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

targetSheet.Range("A6", "G10").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A2", "G6").Value

' Close customer workbook
customerWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: unclear what youre asking. Rows from where? which column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to copy the entire sheet onto a blank sheet in your current workbook and only keep values (your question doesn't specify that too well), you could replace this line:

```
targetSheet.Range("A6", "G10").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A2", "G6").Value
```

With this:

```
sourceSheet.UsedRange.Copy targetSheet.Range("A1")
sourceSheet.UsedRange.Value = sourceSheet.UsedRange.Value
```

Hope that proves to do the trick!

**UPDATE**

---

Baed upon your last comment, try replacing this line:

```
sourceSheet.UsedRange.Copy targetSheet.Range("A1")
```

With this line:

```
Intersect(sourceSheet.UsedRange, sourceSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1,0)).Copy targetSheet.Range("A1")
```

The final part `Range("A1")` can be updated to paste the results wherever you want them.

Hope this does the trick!!

Comment: John, thanks, almost there. I would like to copy everything except the first row. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just the following line has to be changed like I've given below:

```
targetSheet.Range("A6", "G10").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A2", "G6").Value
```

1. First, using name ranges (top-left of excel where the name of the cell appears), name the start and end cell of the source sheet. Say, you call them "start" and "end".
2. Now, you can also name your start cell in targetsheet. End cell is not required because it will paste everything anyways. This is optional and you can stay without naming it like below.
3. The code will then look like...

   ```
   targetSheet.Range("A6").Value = sourceSheet.Range("start", "end").Value
   ```
4. If you name the targetSheet start cell ("start_target" for example) as well then it will be like this :

   ```
   targetSheet.Range("start_target").Value = sourceSheet.Range("start", "end").Value
   ```